# How to shuffle data each time when using cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When training a Ridge Classifier, I'm able to perform 10 fold cross validation like so:

```
clf = linear_model.RidgeClassifier()
n_folds = 10
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=n_folds)
scores
array([0.83236107, 0.83937346, 0.84490172, 0.82985258, 0.84336609,
       0.83753071, 0.83753071, 0.84213759, 0.84121622, 0.84398034])
```

If I want to perform 10 fold cross validation again, and I use:

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=n_folds)
```

I end up with the same results.

Thus, it seems the data is being split the same way both times.
Is there a way to randomly partition the data into n_folds every time I perform cross validation?

Comment: `crorss_val_score` will internally ue StratifiedKFold for a classification task, so you should not get exact same results each time. Are you setting the numpy random seed anywhere? How large is your data?

Comment: could I ask why you are only using train dataset??

Answer (score 5):

What you will want to do is create your own instances of Stratified K Folds object and pass it in to the cv argument in cross_val_score.  This way you can supply different random seeds for splitting the data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
clf = linear_model.RidgeClassifier()
for n in range(5):
     strat_k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=n)
     scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=strat_k_fold)
```

Comment: Aren't you missing shuffle=True?

Comment: If you don't need to do stratified sampling, but just simple k-fold cross-validation, in the previous code you can use `sklearn.model_selection.KFold` instead of `StratifiedKFold`

instead of StratifiedKFold

Comment: What is the reason for using cross_val_score inside a for loop? doesn't it already test it 10 times? So in your code it will have 50 scores?